# OpenCV C++ combine gray images in color image

Tags: c++, opencv, colors

I have three same sized grayscale images and want to combine them in one RGB image. Is there a method for doing that in openCV or do i have to write it on my own?

Example: Gray1 shall be red channel, Gray2 shall be green channel, Gray3 shall be blue channel.

Purpose: Visualize diffrent features of an image in "color layers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV provides a function for that: [Merge](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4)

Example:

```
Mat red, green, blue;
Mat channels[3] = {red, green, blue};
Mat m;
merge(channels, 3, m);
```

Comment: I would swap red & blue though

Comment: @DmitriiZ.True, ideally you would but this is just an example. OP can order the channel as he/she wants.

Comment: Sure, just saying that if OP wanted RGB image as an output - I would've swapped red & blue in your example.